# Can i update many data in one time using API patch on vuejs?

Tags: vue.js, axios, patch

I want to update data from API using axios patch vuejs, but i want to update many data together in one time. for the example i have an object in array with name and value 'isExported : false'. So i make some button like this

```
<v-btn
    dark
    variant="tonal"
    color="#1D6F42"
    class="me-4"
    @click="updateData"
    >Update</v-btn
  >
```

to trigger updateing all datta. So if i click the button, object isExported in all data on the datatables will change value into true 'isExported: true'.

and this is my function

```
updateData() {
  axios.patch(`http://localhost:8080/orders/${user.id}`, { isExported: true })
  .then((response) => {
    user.isExported = true;
    console.log(response);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error("Error updating data:", error);
  });
},
```

but it does'nt work, and appear error like this

**axios post request error with 422 (Unprocessable Entity)**

Comment: It's a bad network request, not related to Vue.  "[422 Unprocessable Content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/422) response status code indicates that the server understands the content type of the request entity, and the syntax of the request entity is correct, but it was unable to process the contained instructions."  Try logging/debugging the request on your backend.  If you need more help, [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76773572/edit) your question to include the technical details of the endpoint and what kind of request data and formatting it expects.